# update page content

Tags: components, refresh

I have a morris chart that compares different students statistics. I also have a modal in which I can add a new student and the graph should update with new student statistics. After adding, the graph is getting updated but only when I refresh the whole page. How would I update the page without refreshing?

component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }
getData() {
        this.http.get('url')
          .subscribe(data => {

            const graphData = data.stathistory;
            const graphDataArr = [];
            let currentChar = 'a';

            for (const graphdata in graphData) {
              const curDate = graphdata.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, '$1-$2-$3');
              const graphdataObj = { 'y': curDate };

              for (const element in graphData[graphdata]) {
                graphdataObj[currentChar] = Number(graphData[graphdata][element].rank);
                currentChar = this.nextChar(currentChar);
              }

              graphDataArr.push(graphdataObj)
              currentChar = 'a';
            }

            const yKeysArr = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < data.domains.length; i++) {
              yKeysArr.push(currentChar);
              currentChar = this.nextChar(currentChar);
            }
            this.generateChart(graphDataArr, data.names, yKeysArr);
          });
      }

      generateChart(graphRanks = [], names = [], yKeys = []) {

        this.graphData = graphRanks;
        this.graphOptions = {
          xkey: 'y',
          ykeys: yKeys,
          labels: names,
          resize: true,
          parseTime: false,
          pointSize: 0,
        };

      }


addStudent(name) {
    this.http.post('url', {
      name: name,
    })
      .subscribe(response => {
          this.getData();
      }
      );
  }
```

html

```
    <div *ngIf = 'graphData'  mk-morris-js [options]="graphOptions" [data]="graphData" type="Line" style="height: 500px; width: 100%;">

**code for modal dialog**

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addStudent(name)">
```

Please let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working. I tried to clear the morris chart and generate the chart with new data. So, whenever there is a data change, it would clear the graph and redraw the graph with new data.

Clearing the chart

```
document.getElementById('idofthegraph').innerHTML = '';
```

This would draw the chart again

```
this.generateChart(graphDataArr, data.names, yKeysArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks fine. I would suggest you to add console.log(graphRanks); just before this.graphData = graphRanks; to ensure that the new data is loaded when expected. By the way your button calls the function *addDomain(name)* while in your script the function name is *addStudent(name)*.

Comment: Yes, I did add a console.log and I could see the new data. But the graph is showing new data only when page is refreshed. I edited the question now to call addStudent(name)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you make your graphData an observable and use the async pipe in your html. Something like this:

```
graphData$ = this.http.get('url').pipe(
    map(x => // do stuff with x here)
)
```

Then, in your html you can make:

```
[graphData]="graphData$ | async"
```

Here is a good post by Todd Motto on the ng-if piece:
https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-async-pipe

EDIT:

If you don't want to make your graphData an observable - you could probably use a switchMap in you addStudent function.

```
addStudent(name) {
this.http.post('url', {
  name: name,
})
  .pipe(
      switchMap(x => this.getData())
  }
  );
```

}